# Building Notification through an Interface callback

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am running into a issue trying to build a notification using an interface that I have implemented.

The interface implements a handler which has 4 methods, the method I have having issue with is the onNotificationReceived()

Here is the error

`The constructor NotificationCompat.Builder(new MQTTCommunicator.MQTTEventHandler(){}) is undefined`

public interface MQTTCommunicator {
  void connect(String address, int port);// add ability to add several connections

**What can I do to fix this issue? I attempted to cast is to a MQTTEventHandler, but no luck.** I have it set up this way because all the code is implemented in a library, and I would like to avoid hard-coding any classes/references to the an application project.

**Interface Base Class**

```
  void disconnect();

  void subscribe(String topic);

  void unsubscribe(String topic);

  void sendMessage(String topic, String message);

  void addEventHandler(MQTTEventHandler handler);

  void removeEventHandler(MQTTEventHandler handler);

  CommunicatorStatus getStatus();


  public interface MQTTEventHandler {
    void onStatusChanged(CommunicatorStatus status, String message);

    void onMessageReceived(String topic, String message);

    void onException(String message);

    void onNotificationReceived(String message);
  }
```

**This is inside an Activity, where I create an instance of a class which implements my base interface class.**

I named this object mComm, and I am able to register an MQTTEventHandler to it.

```
 private void establishRecievers() {
    MQTTEventHandler mHandler = new MQTTEventHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onStatusChanged(CommunicatorStatus status, String message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Do something with status
      }

      @Override
      public void onMessageReceived(String topic, String message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Do something with the message
        adapter.add(topic + "|||" + message);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

      }

      @Override
      public void onException(String message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Do something with exception
      }

      public void onNotificationReceived(String message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Do something with exception
        Log.e("NOTIFICATION", message);

     //ISSUE IS HERE

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!");

      }
    };
    mComm.addEventHandler(mHandler);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using `getApplicationContext();`

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(topic).setContentText(message);
```